# Get only one record after join from matching columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have two tables like below.

```
Table1
Join-Column
Join-Column-value1
Join-Column-value2
Join-Column-value3

Table 2
Join-Column            Other-Column
Join-Column-value1     Other-Column-Value-1
Join-Column-value1     Other-Column-Value-2
Join-Column-value2     Other-Column-Value-3
```

I want to join Table1 with Table2 on column `Join-Column` and output any one matching record of `Other-Column`. In the above example, `Join-Column-value1` matches two records from Table2. I want to output any one of `Other-Column-Value-1`, `Other-Column-Value-2` but not both. `Join-Column-value2` matches only one record from Table2 so I want to output `Other-Column-Value-3` also. The desired output based on above example is:

```
Other-Column
Other-Column-Value-1
Other-Column-Value-3
```

How do I do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select t1.join_column, any_value(t2.other_column) other_column
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.join_column = t1.join_column
group by t1.join_column
```

In MySQL, [aggregate function `ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) comes close to what you seem to want - but there are other, deterministic alternatives, such as `MIN()` or `MAX()`.